# how to generate the mark `dot at the right corner ` in R

Tags: r

Germany , Italy  and  Romania   adopted the use of the decimal mark and the thousands separator this way ,when they write `1234567.89`,they express it as

```
  1˙234˙567,89
```

how can i format `1234567.89` into  `1˙234˙567,89`?

Comment: formatC(1234567.89, format="f", big.mark="\u02D9", decimal.mark=",")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the start of developing a system to handle such a numeric format.

```
 setClass("MidEuroNum")
 setAs("character", "MidEuroNum",
         function(from) as.numeric(sub(",",".", gsub("\\\u02D9", "",  from) ) )
      )
xx <- 1234567.89
class(xx) <- c('MidEuroNum', 'numeric')
print.MidEuroNum <- function(x, ...) suppressWarnings(print(
                      formatC(x, 
                          format="f", big.mark="\u02D9", decimal.mark=",", digits=2)))
 print(xx)
#[1] "1˙234˙567,89"
 xx
[1] "1˙234˙567,89"
 inherits(xx, "numeric")
#[1] TRUE
```

This class stuff can be tricky. I also tried:

```
setClass("MidEuroNum", contains="numeric")
```

And the little surprises seemed to decrease.

```
> as(xx, "MidEuroNum")
[1] "1˙234˙567,89"
> inherits(as(xx, "MidEuroNum"), "numeric")
[1] TRUE
> as(xx, "MidEuroNum") +2000   # seems to behave itsel with ordinary operations and numbers
[1] "1˙236˙567,89"

read.table( text="1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89
+ 1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89", colClasses="MidEuroNum")
       V1      V2      V3
1 1234568 1234568 1234568
2 1234568 1234568 1234568
```

Checking to see if the numers to the right of the "decimal" got handle correctly:

```
print(
      read.table( text="1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89
                        1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89 1˙234˙567,89",
              colClasses="MidEuroNum")[1,1],
      digits=10)
#[1] 1234567.89
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the function `formatC`, Click [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formatc.html) for more info.

```
> formatC(1234567.89, format="f", big.mark="`", decimal.mark=",")
[1] "1`234`567,8900"
```

A few explanations of the flags that I am using:

`big.mark`: character; if not empty used as mark between every big.interval decimals before (hence big) the decimal point and the big.interval default value is 3.

`decimal.mark`: the character to be used to indicate the numeric decimal point

You can do more reading and figure out how to remove the trailing zeros by reading the format flag.

Comment: +1 - Using the `˙` for `big.mark` seems to give an odd result of `"1™Ë234™Ë567,89"` however - some encoding issue presumably?

Comment: @thelatemail I have the same weird output.. do you know the unicode for that sign?? how do you call it? upper period?

Comment: "dot above" apparently - http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x02D9/index.html - works in `paste(1:3,collapse="\u02D9")` but can't seem to replicate it for `formatC`

Comment: @thelatemail I took a quick look at the source code.. formatC is calling prettyNum and inside prettyNum there is a line in the end: A. <- paste0(B., c(decimal.mark, "")[iN + 1L], A.) and I have no problem using the upper period as the decimal separator... will do more research